# How to change value inside list without changing list (Python)

Tags: python, list

How do you change a value from positive to negative inside a list when you need it, without changing list itself.

Example(sorry will be a bit of Maya, but i think even people who doesn't know Maya will get it) :

```
someList = [1.7, 18.9, -0.3]
cmds.joint(n="test", p=someList)
```

and I want in this case, `someList = [-1.7, 18.9, -0.3]` - "1.7" make negative.

So I was wondering if there is a way to make it without creating different list or changing existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change `someList`, you can try this:

```
someList = [1.7, 18.9, -0.3]
cmds.joint(n="test", p=[-someList[0]] + someList[1:])
```

It makes 1.7 negative and concatenates it to the rest of the `someList`.

Answer (score 1):

```
someList[0] = -someList[0]
```

where 0 is index. If you don't know index and just value say 1.7

```
indx = someList.index(1.7)
someList[indx] = -someList[indx]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reinitialize the same index

```
someList[0]=-someList[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is job for list comprehension. Multiply by (-1) on the fly:

```
for x in [[x*-1] for x in someList]:
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
[-1.7]
[-18.9]
[0.3]
```